# How to use Link tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

As mentioned in the nextjs docs, I couldn't do client side routing via the `Link` tag when used on a  `div`, though I can navigate if used on the anchor tag.
I'm using nextjs v6.0.3

```
import Link from "next/link";
export default ({ src, title }) => (
 <Link href="/one">
    <div className="element">
        <div className="img-container">
            <img src={src} />
        </div>
        <style jsx>{`
    .element{
        width: 30%;
        height: auto;
        margin:10px;
        border-radius:50%;
    }
    .img-container{
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
    }
    img{
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
    }
    .event-title{
        text-align:center;
    }
    `}

        </style>
        <div className="event-title"><p>{title}</p></div>
    </div >
</Link>

)
```

Comment: In this component in `pages` directory or outside the `pages` directory ? or can you try wrapping the `Link` in a div ?

Comment: This component lies outside the pages directory.I tried wrapping doesn't work though.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 6):

You are using style tag in wrong place thats creating the issue. Try to use it like this as mentioned in nextjs documentation.

```
 <div>
    <Link href='/one'>
      <div className='element'>
        <div className='img-container'>
          <img src={src} />
        </div>
        <div className='event-title'><p>{title}</p></div>
      </div>
    </Link>
    <style jsx>{`
      .element{
          width: 30%;
          height: auto;
          margin:10px;
          border-radius:50%;
      }
      .img-container{
          width:100%;
          height:auto;
      }
      img{
          width:100%;
          height:auto;
      }
      .event-title{
          text-align:center;
      }
      `}
    </style>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Import the library first at the top of the page

```
import Link from "next/link";
```

Then use it like that

```
<Link href={'/'} params={'id': 1}>
  <a>link</a>
</.Link>
```

if useing node js router href linked by name route

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your question is since you seem to answer it yourself by stating that you can't use  with a div and still have it route. But to reiterate, if you are using  with an element other than  the href will not be passed, only the onClick event. You'd have to trigger the routing yourself based on the onClick. It seems to me that just converting the  to an  would allow you still route to /one.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding for such a problem, it only happens in development mode.. Can you please verify this for me?

Try this as a work around, put that listener on you `componentDidMount` lifecycle method in `pages/_app.js`.

```
import Router from 'next/router';

Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const els = document.querySelectorAll('link[href*="/_next/static/css/styles.chunk.css"]');
    const timestamp = new Date().valueOf();
    els[0].href = '/_next/static/css/styles.chunk.css?v=' + timestamp;
  }
});
```

From: [Relative issue discussen](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/282)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this trick and it is working fine.
In the file `_app.js`, import an empty css file:

```
import "../assets/css/empty.css";
```

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, such as how/why it works, and maybe even a source link.

Comment: I have read on github of nextjs, I don't find the link at the moment but I got explanation that the chunk file  does not re-generated if we don't import css file. It's still working good actually

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```js
<Link href="/one">
```

with this:

```js
<Link route="/one">
```